# getToken(senderId, scope) throw IOException: INVALID_TARGET_VERSION

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I compile my app with target 30 (Android 11) the method
`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderId, scope)` throw out the exception java.io.IOException: INVALID_TARGET_VERSION.

If I compile the app for Android Q instead, it works fine.

How can I set multi-senderID with an app with target 30?

Answer (score 3):

I got an official response from the Firebase team, It is no longer possible to use the getToken(senderId, scope) method passing multiple senderIDs, but we must make a request for each senderID. I write it here maybe it can be useful to someone.